# Generating random value in a range that changes over time

Tags: python, date, datetime, random

I am trying to generate random values in a range of [1800,1600] over a certain period. That range is very strict, but I need to have a smaller range that is flexible over the period.

An example of what I am looking for would be:
for the first 10 days, select a random value between [1705,1695]
for the next 10 days, select a random number between [1695, 1685]

However, I would like the range to either randomly increase 10 or decrease 10.

So far, the only way I have been able to do this is by manually setting a range and then random generate values for a certain time period with the range. I would like the range to be able to be randomly selected.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: And what do you want to happen when it you're at the range 1605-1615? Do you want it to either stay there or increase since a decrease would take it out of bounds?

Comment: Use `datetime.date.toordinal()` to find the limits of your strict range; pick spans of integers within this range and use `datetime.date.fromordinal()`  to convert to datetime objects.

Comment: Sorry for not writing the question better. Thank you for the advice. The code takes awhile to run for the data set I am trying to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a shot at the problem as you've described it. This will generate random numbers for `n` periods of 10 days.

```
import numpy as np

n = 10    
lower = 1695 # starting lower bound
upper = 1705 # starting upper bound

min_lower = 1600
max_upper = 1800

values = np.array([])
for period in range(n):
    values = np.append(values, np.random.randint(lower, upper, 10))

    if np.random.randint(2): # attempt to increase bound
        if upper+10 < max_upper: # increase bounds
            lower += 10
            upper += 10
        # else: bounds stay the same
    else: # attempt to decrease bound
        if lower-10 > min_lower: # decrease bounds
            lower -= 10
            upper -= 10
        # else: bounds stay the same
```

Here is a plot showing the results of generating numbers for 10 time periods of length 10. You can see that each period is bounded by a range of 10.

[image: Example]

You might have to make some small adjustments based on your needs. When the bounds bump into the limits, they remain the same.

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you very much.